# How to redirect after end of css animation using javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have the two scripts below:

```
function redirect(id) {
    window.location="somewebsite.com?parameter=" + id;
}

function addClassByClick(div){              
    document.getElementById(div).setAttribute('class','magictime magic');
}
```

and i'm using the onclick event to call the animation, but the redirect works before the end of animation, below the code to call:

```
<i class="fa fa-trash-o" onclick=\'addClassByClick("trash-' . substr($t['target'], 1) .'");redirect(' . $t['code'] . ');\'></i>
```

I've tried use setTimeout function but didn't work.

Comment: You can put the redirect inside addClassByClick() function.

Comment: @nnunes10 i've tried this before too.

Comment: There is no way you can judge animation is completed..`setTimout` could be a _hack_

Comment: @RayonDabre Yes there is, [here is some reading](http://www.sitepoint.com/css3-animation-javascript-event-handlers/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the setTimeout function works great, i was using it with the wrong format, below the solution

```
function addClassByClick(div, id) {
    document.getElementById(div).setAttribute('class', 'magictime puffOut');

    setTimeout(function(){
        window.location = "somewebsite.com?parameter=" + id;
    }, 1000);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

1) remove 'redirect' call from onClick.

2) you can use events **transitionend** and **animationend**

```
function redirect(id) {
    window.location = "somewebsite.com?parameter=" + id;
}

/* From Modernizr */
function whichTransitionEvent() {
    var t;
    var el = document.createElement('fakeelement');
    var transitions = {
        'transition': 'transitionend',
        'OTransition': 'oTransitionEnd',
        'MozTransition': 'transitionend',
        'WebkitTransition': 'webkitTransitionEnd'
    };
    for (t in transitions) {
        if (el.style[t] !== undefined) {
            return transitions[t];
        }
    }
}

function addClassByClick(div) {
    var transitionEvent = whichTransitionEvent();
    transitionEvent && e.addEventListener(transitionEvent, function () {
        redirect()
    });
    var transitionEnd = document.getElementById(div).setAttribute('class', 'magictime magic');
}
```

The "whichTransitionEvent" can be swapped for "animation" instead of "transition" texts, as can the usage :)